# How to create VSTS Service Endpoint using Azure Keyvault secrets

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

Am working on VSTS CI&CD. For that, am trying to create “Azure Resource Manager” Service Endpoint as a VSTS Connection. But, here I don’t want give SPN credentials i.e. “Client Id and Client Secret” directly for making connection, in spite of that I need to pass SPN Credentials which are in Keyvault secrets saved in Azure keyvault. Is this possible, that the VSTS Service Endpoint creation using Azure Keyvault Secrets. If possible, please suggest me to “How to done it”

Answer (score 0):

Currently, VSTS can support the below [list of service endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=vsts#common-service-connection-types)

> 1. Azure Classic service connection
> 2. Azure Resource Manager service connection
> 3. Azure Service Bus service connection
> 4. Bitbucket Cloud service enconnectiondpoint
> 5. Chef service connection
> 6. Docker Host service connection
> 7. Docker Registry service connection
> 8. External Git service connection
> 9. Generic service connection
> 10. GitHub service connection
> 11. GitHub Enterprise service connection
> 12. Jenkins service connection
> 13. Kubernetes service connection
> 14. npm service connection
> 15. NuGet service connection
> 16. Service Fabric service connection
> 17. SSH service connection
> 18. Subversion service connection
> 19. Team Foundation Server / VSTS service connection
> 20. Visual Studio App Center service connection

You need the `ARM Service connection` for at least connecting to the `AzureKeyVault`. I think you are bit worry to store the SPN *(Client Id and client Secrets)* in VSTS credentials. Actually, you don't need to worry about it. This credentials will be stored securely and can't be visible to other after it created.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Jayandran. Yes, you are right that the connection credentials will be store securely. But, here we don't have access to use SPN credentials directly. We need to go through with KeyVault secrets.

Comment: @Mani understood. As a workaround, you can create an SPN for your AzureKeyVault then retrieve the secrets using [Azure Powershell task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petergroenewegen.PeterGroenewegen-Xpirit-Vsts-Build-InlinePowershell), but this will not help you to create a service endpoint in VSTS. Currently, there is **no way** to create a service endpoint whose client id and client secret are kept in az keyvault. You can create your OWN feedback for this in [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services) if you want this feature

Comment: OK @Jayandran, I will try it once. Thank you

Comment: @Mani Is there any update on my answer above ? Could you please accept/upvote my answer ,so that it can help the community as well

Comment: No @Jayandran. Still, am searching for this

Comment: @Mani maybe you should try the [Azure DevOps API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to create the service principle instead of focusing on UI